# Overwrite a file instead of appending to it?

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm a newbie linux programmer that ordered to be a sitin for my colleague.

I opened up a file with this line:

```
err = open("path/foo.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0777);
```

And now I write to it, and hexdump the file, the output showed that I appended
new content instead of overwriting the original.

How do I overwrite?

Also if you ask me "wth is "open"?" I'd refer to the newbie defense and say I don't know. The closest thing I know is fopen but I don't know what library/framework my colleague is using. Posix perhaps?

Comment: You might want to read the documentation of `open()`.

Comment: You want to truncate the file, add the O_TRUNC flag. Use the `man 2 open` command to see the documentation.

Comment: In all fairness, the documentation of this function is as awful as the function itself. Any function taking an octal constant as parameter was clearly not well-designed. Why such ancient crap APIs are still being used is beyond me.

Comment: @Lundin Octal is great when you need to use bits it groups of three, like the "rwe" protection-bits of Unix. :) And POSIX specifies symbolic constants for all of these IIRC.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There exists no situation where "magic numbers" are great. But since these functions are from the Jurassic era somewhere, good programming practices had yet to be invented. As for why they were added to POSIX some 20-30 years later, well there's no excuse for that.

Comment: @AlexSveshnikov trunc doesn't work.

Comment: you should use `O_TRUNC`, to erase file contents, previous to writting to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the manual for `open(2)` via `man 2 open`, you will find a list of accepted flags.

You should be reading man pages in any case and it's not hard, the only things you need to remember is that you can search for keywords by pressing `/`, `n`/`N` for jumping between things that were found, and `q` to exit when you're done, everything else is superfluous and may only speed things up a little.

The flag you're looking for is

```
O_TRUNC
If the file already exists and is a regular file and the access mode allows
writing (i.e., is  O_RDWR  or O_WRONLY)  it  will be truncated to length 0.
If the file is a FIFO or terminal device file, the O_TRUNC flag is ignored.
Otherwise, the effect of O_TRUNC is unspecified.
```

So all you have to do is add this flag whenever you want to overwrite the file completely.

But if you can, you should be using `fopen(3)`, in which case the `mode` you're looking for is `w+`, and it is equivalent to `O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC` in `open(2)`.

`open(2)` is a low level system call and reading from a raw file descriptor efficiently and correctly is not that simple, `FILE*` you get from `fread(3)` on the other hand is an implementation that handles most of details like buffering for you, and unless you can do better, you shouldn't be avoiding it.

---

By the way, `0777` file permission is rarely needed and doesn't apply to regular files, I'd recommend you open normal text files with `0666`, which does everything you need except does not enable it to be executed as a program.